# Chromium error while trying to install aws-azure-login

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, azure, npm-install

When I try to install the aws-azure-login using the following command npm install -g aws-azure-login on Windows 10, I get the following error...

```
npm WARN deprecated cheerio-select-tmp@0.1.1: Use cheerio-select instead
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\BUCS002\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-azure-login\node_modules\puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r818858! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
npm ERR! Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1531:34)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:378:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:945:8)
npm ERR!     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:719:12) {
npm ERR!   code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\BUCS002\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-31T21_18_10_823Z-debug.log
```

I also get this additional info in the logs...

```
922 verbose stack Error: command failed
922 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BUCS002\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
922 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
922 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
922 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
923 verbose pkgid puppeteer@5.5.0
924 verbose cwd C:\Program Files\Cmder
925 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
926 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\BUCS002\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "aws-azure-login"
927 verbose node v15.11.0
928 verbose npm  v7.7.6
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

under the hood `aws-azure-login` is using `puppeteer`, which is relying on `chromium`, to be able to use it you have to install it first, something like

```
node C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-azure-login\node_modules\puppeteer\install.js
```

replace your username in the path, the command will install required Chromium version somewhere here

```
C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-azure-login\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, our enterprise [proxy](https://www.netskope.com/products/capabilities/ssl-tls-inspection) client trying to inspect the SSL traffic by presenting its own Self Signed certificate which is trusted in my local truststore. So we have to download these CAcert using OpenSSL commands &  using "NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS" argument to specify the additional downloaded cert path, we were able to download & install the puppeteer on my MacOS.

Here are the steps:

1. download the CAcert that enterprise proxy presents when we try to connect to any domain [storage.googleapis.com].

   ```
   > openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -servername storage.googleapis.com -connect storage.googleapis.com:443 < /dev/null | awk '/BEGIN/,/END/{ if(/BEGIN/){a++}; out="cert"a".crt"; print >out}' && for cert in *.crt; do newname=$(openssl x509 -noout -subject -in $cert | sed -n 's/^.*CN=\(.*\)$/\1/; s/[ ,.*]/_/g; s/__/_/g; s/^_//g;p').pem; mv $cert $newname; done
   ```
2. The above command will download all the domain, intermediate & root certificates of the Proxy. Concatenate all the certificates into a single PEM file.

   > cat domain1.crt intermediate.crt root.crt >extra_cacert.pem
3. Specify the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS argument while installing the puppeteer using npm

   > NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=./extra_cacert.pem node /Users/velayutham/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js

*****The above steps were tested in MacOS!!!*****